# Combining Edge and Document Collections in AQL

Tags: arangodb, aql

Is it possible to query, through the same AQL query, several collections effectivelly (with index speed) being some of those edge or document collections? I wanted to emulate more or less the behaviour of foreign keys on RDBMs on tables using edges.

Thanx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using document fields which are indexed by default then the behaviour is similar to foreign keys in RDBMS. For example, by default, document type collections indexes `_id` field and edge type collections indexes `_id`, `_from` and `_to` fields. AQL functions such as `EDGES` or `NEIGHBORS` are using these indexes to query relevant data.

Answer (score 5):

I can confirm: EDGES() and NEIGHBORS() will use the automatically available indexes on the _from and/or _to attributes in the edge collections.

You may also join manually using a FILTER clause, e.g.

```
FOR ...
  FILTER e._from == something_else._id
  RETURN ...
```